# Mvc3 WebGrid ajaxUpdateContainerId duplicates the container

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I don't know if it is a bug just at my site, but the WebGrid apparently duplicates the container specified on the ajaxUpdateContainerId. Here's my code:

```
<div id="grid-wrapper" class="grid-wrapper">
@{
    var a = new []
    {
        new { Mensagens = 3, Nome = "Rodrigo Manguinho", Agendamento = "08:00", Prazo = 2, Tipo = "Novo", Percentual = "30%"},
        new { Mensagens = 5, Nome = "Rodrigo Manguinho", Agendamento = "08:00", Prazo = 2, Tipo = "Novo", Percentual = "30%"}
    };

    var grid = new WebGrid(source: a, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid-wrapper");

    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "grid round-3", alternatingRowStyle: "even", rowStyle: "odd", htmlAttributes: new { @cellpadding = "0px", @cellspacing = "0px" });
}
</div>
```

When i check the firebug the div grid-wrapper has another div with the same id and class. It duplicate when i click any TH link to sort the table.

Answer (score 3):

We just had the same problem that you had. We analyzed the source code for the WebGrid controller and apparently the bug exists and cannot be changed because it's hardcoded:

**Taken from "mvc3-rtm-sources\webpages\src\System.Web.Helpers\WebGrid\WebGrid.cs", lines 17-22:**

```
namespace System.Web.Helpers {
    public class WebGrid {
        // jquery code for partial page update of grid components (see http://api.jquery.com/load/)
        private const string _ajaxLinkScript = "$(\'#{0}\').load(\'{1} #{0}\');";
        private const string _ajaxLinkScriptWithCallback = "$(\'#{0}\').load(\'{1} #{0}\', {2});";
```

As you can see, the ajax links cannot be changed from the external API. Fortunately, we found a way to fix this, and also make it work with both JavaScript enabled or disabled:

```
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "myDivId", ajaxUpdateCallback: "myFunctionName");
    WebGrid gridNoJS = new WebGrid(Model);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(myFunctionName);

    function myFunctionName() {
        $('#myDivId table tfoot a').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.attr('onclick', $this.attr('onclick').replace('#myDivId\',', '#myDivId table\','));
        });

        $('#myDivId table tfoot div').show();
    }
</script>

<div id="myDivId">
    @grid.Table(
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("MyColumn1", header: "MyColumn1"),
            grid.Column("MyColumn2", header: "MyColumn2")),
        footer: @<text><noscript>@gridNoJS.Pager()</noscript><div style="display:none">@grid.Pager()</div></text>
    )
</div>
```

You can also extrapolate this idea to fix the sort links as well.

Comment: Nice. Ill try ur suggestion. Thanks for share.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you at all, but I was having the same problem.  I was having the same problem and was able to fix it.  In my case, I had set the ajaxContainerUpdateId to the same id as the grid html Id.  Instead, I had to put a container div around the webgrid and set the ajaxUpdateContainerId to the Id of the div, and give the WebGrid a different id in the GetHtml Method. The first part of my grid declaration is shown below where searchContainer is a div that contains the grid.GetHtml method.

```
var grid = new System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: ViewData["pagesize"] != null ? (int)ViewData["pagesize"] : 20, canSort: true,ajaxUpdateContainerId:"searchContainer");
grid.Bind(Model.Records, rowCount: Model.TotalResults, autoSortAndPage: false);
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
grid.SortColumn = ViewData["sortColumn"].ToString();
grid.SortDirection = ViewData["sortDir"].ToString().ToLower() == "asc" ? SortDirection.Ascending : SortDirection.Descending;
@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "searchgrid", @class = "grid" }, alternatingRowStyle: "alt" ,
```

Comment: Hello Ronnie. If you notice, in my exemple I did it. I was using the Grid ID on the ajaxUpdateContainerId, but when i noticed that my Table was being duplicated I changed to the wrapper ID. Visually it looks ok, but if you check the source code, the wrapper is also duplicated.

Comment: Oh, I guess I didn't look at the source that closely.  I did not realize that the container was being duplicated.  I did notice what I believe to be an error in the generated onclick handler for the header link.  I think it should be $("#containerId").load("/ajax/test.html","#gridId") , but the  grid uses the ajaxUpdateContainerId for both values ("containerId and grid id") in my above example.  I think that may be the problem, but I am not sure.